# Responsive image grid causes decimal pixels which makes images not fit on one row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive, pixel, mdbootstrap

I'm using a 3x3 image grid with Lightbox (in MDBootstrap).
The images all have a 33% width (including padding).

All images are retrieved from the Instagram Basic Display API.
These images usually have a native resolution of 1440x1440px.
However, sometimes, for some odd reason, an image will have a resolution of 1440x1441 (one pixel wider).

Putting these images that are one pixel higher in a grid, scaling them down to 33% width, will cause them to be slightly larger, which thereby causes 3 images to no longer fit on one row. Please see example below:

[image: The middle image in the top row is actually 1440x1441 in stead of 1440x1440, which causes it to be 156.094px wide when scaled down.]

As you can see, the images aren't aligned in a 3x3 grid. I found out that this is caused by the second image in the top row, which is actually 156 in width by 156.094px in height(!). This is obviously caused by the image provided by Instagram being 1440x1441 (in stead of 1440x1440):

[image]

I have tried using display: inline-table on the image object as someone in another topic suggested (to round down decimal pixels), but this didn't work. Manually resizing the image to 155.891px x 156px (using Inspect Element in Chrome) makes the image fit:

[image]

So my question is: without having to check every image's width with javascript and resizing all of them to the same height, how can I make sure the image has an exact 1:1 aspect ratio as opposed to ~1:1.001 to prevent this from happening?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: fixed switching height/width around, thanks @CBroe

Comment: _“which is actually 156 in height by 156.094px in width”_ - no, exactly the other way around. The first value is the width, the second one is the height. And elements of different height, easily cause this kind of problem in a float-based column layout. Switch to flexbox, and the whole problem will disappear.

Comment: Have you tryed placing images in a container with fixed width and then applying to `img` css property `object-fit: cover;`?

Comment: @CBroe you're right, I switched height and width around (because I thought more height wouldn't cause the 4th image to jump to the next row), but my problem remains the same. What do you mean exactly by switching to flexbox?

Comment: A simple flexbox grid layout, using flex wrapping.

Comment: @ciekals11 The image width needs to be responsive (approx 33% of the screen) so a fixed width wouldn't work

Comment: @LaurensSwart by fixed width I meant this 33%. The in container width width like that place your image and make its width,height 100% and `object-fit: cover`

Comment: I have tried wrapping it in a div. The problem is, the lightbox UI relies on the image being in a <figure> wrapper and adding a div inside this doesn't work very well (basically, it breaks things when I set the width of this div, even if I use percentages). Also, at some point, the images will wrap to 4 on a row or 5 (depending on screen width). So I am really looking for a solution that I can apply to the <img> object itself, making the image have an exact aspect ratio of 1:1.